# Having trouble allowing people to BUMP a unique entry in table

Tags: php, mysql

So, my table has a bunch of codes in it and I don't want more than one of the same code in the table so I have it as "UNIQUE."
But, at the same time, I want them to be able to bump their code once every hour.

```
function some_more_custom_content() {

    $output="<BR>";

    ob_start();

    if ($_REQUEST['code'] != "") {
        $code = $_REQUEST['code'];
        $query="INSERT INTO `fc` (`code`,`datetime`) values ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($code) . "', now())";
        $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $seconds = time() - strtotime($fetch_array["datetime"]);
        if($sql){
            echo("Intserted " . htmlentities($code) ." into the top.");
        }else{
            if ($seconds < 60*60) {
                echo ("The code " . htmlentities($code) ." was updated less than an hour ago.");
         } else {
                $query="DELETE FROM `fc` (`code`,`datetime`) values ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($code) . "', now())";
                echo ("Inserted " . htmlentities($code) ." into the top.");
        }

    }}
```

Now, I tried to get it so that when the code works it submits the code as normal, which I think works.

Now, if it gets a code that is already there I get the duplicate error "Duplicate entry 'Bob' for key 1"

But, I just want it to delete the old query that it found and to resubmit if it's been more than one hour since last submission.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: btw, you should have added this to your previous questions and not open a new one

Comment: How many times have you asked the same question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241649/having-trouble-allowing-people-to-bump-a-unique-entry-in-table
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236386/allowing-users-to-bump-an-input-they-submitted-every-hour

Answer (score 1):

You can just update the date/time field in the database to reflect the time of the "bump".

```
if ($_REQUEST['code'] != "")
{
    $code = $_REQUEST['code'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM fc WHERE code = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($code) . "'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $seconds = time() - strtotime($row["datetime"]);

        if ($seconds > 60*60)
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE fc SET datetime = NOW() WHERE code = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($code) . "'";

            mysql_query($sql);
            echo("Intserted " . htmlentities($code) ." into the top.");
        }
        else
        {
            echo ("The code " . htmlentities($code) ." was updated less than an hour ago.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO fc (code, datetime) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($code) . "', NOW())";

        mysql_query($sql);
        echo("Intserted " . htmlentities($code) ." into the top.");
    }
}
```

(I probably shouldn't have re-written your code for you, and there are a few more improvements that could be made, but that reflects the best changes I can make with the minimum of changes (does that make any sense?))

Comment: there is no need in two different queries and no need to do a select statement before for checking the current status since MySQL offers this wonderful ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE feature

Answer (score 0):

Frank, you do not need two different queries

```
$query="INSERT INTO `fc` (`code`,`datetime`) 
         values ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($code) . "', now())
         ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE datetime = case when now() - interval 1 hour > `datetime` 
                                      then NOW() 
                                      else `datetime` 
                                         end";
```